# How to access class variable of super class without explicit super class name

Tags: python, inheritance, class-variables

As the title stated, I want to get how to accessing class variable of super class without explicit super class name. Or whether that is possible.

I am NOT talking about accessing **instance variable**, **but class variable**.

For example, if i want to override a class variable in the following example, I have to explicitly use Parent.class_variable.

```
class Parent():
    class_variable = 'this_is_class_variable'

class Child(Parent):
    class_variable = Parent.class_variable + ' in child class'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't easily do what you want to do, because class `Child` isn't a class until after you're done defining it. Since it's not a class, it doesn't have any parents. Potentially you could do it with some kind of metaprogramming; could be fun to hack on.

Comment: @kindall. Thanks for the explanation. Simple and clear. Do you mind making it an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: Thank you for all down voting without leaving a reason or a solution or a suggestion. That's definitely making Stackoverflow a more 'helpful' place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily do what you want to do, because `Child` isn't a class until after you're done defining it. Since it's not a class yet, it doesn't have any parents.

Potentially you could do it with some kind of metaprogramming; could be fun to hack on. The approach I'd take is to write a proxy object that represents an attribute of the parent class. It needs to accumulate the operations that are to be performed on it (such as concatenation using `+` as in your example) rather than performing them immediately. A metaclass or decorator then goes through the finalized class looking for attributes that are instances of this class and forces their evaluation in the context of the parent class (which can be determined from the class's `__mro__` attribute).

This is lot of work, so I'll leave an actual implementation as an exercise for the reader. ;-)